# can't see fire in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I made a fire+smoke simulation as shown:[image]

then when I render, it shows only the block of domain but I want to see fire in rendered view please help me how to fix it the screenshot of rendered view is:[image]

Answer (score 0):

does the domain object have a domain materiel ? if it does not (have a materiel) follow this tutorial https://youtu.be/u-zK7Bu8cAI.